# Identity comparison between booleans and integers

Tags: python

I've been playing and found this.

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for an object’s identity: x is y is true if and only if x and y are the same object. An Object’s identity is determined using the `id()` function. x is not y yields the inverse truth value.

```py
>>> list(map(id, [0, 1, True, not False, False, not True]))
[94660352164256, 94660352164288, 94660351988128, 94660351988128, 94660351988096, 94660351988096]
```

Right now everything is ok: `0`, `1`, `True` and `False` have different ids, as they are different objects. And they are:

```py
>>> True is 1
False
>>> False is 0
False
>>> not False is True
True
>>> not True is False
True
```

But then:

```
>>> not False is 1
True
>>> not True is 0
True
>>>
```

My question is: **How is it possible that at the same time `True is not 1`, `not False is True` and `not False is 1` all return `True`?**

Comment: `not x is y` is equivalent to `x is not y`.

Comment: `not x is y` is a non-idiomatic way to spell `x is not y`. It's not `(not x) is y` at all.

Comment: `not True is 0` == `not (True is 0)`. Check out the [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with priorities & operator precedence. Think of it like this:

`(True is not 1)`, `not (False is True)`, `not (False is 1)`.

Now everything should make sense.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `is` is before `not`.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

so:

```
not False is 1 => not (False is 1) => not False => True
```

and:

```
not True is 0 => not (True is 0) => not False => True
```